# how to easily change output of BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I would like to make the output of `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` configurable, ie remove the timestamp and/or threadid and/or severity. Current output is eg this

> [2016-01-17 17:26:22.609294] [0x00007fc4b8dbd840] [fatal] "my MSG"

What would be the easiest way to achieve this while still using trivial logging and minimal extra? In addition, maybe change the formatting of timestamp or provide a name of thread instead of thread id.

Thanks,
filimon

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by creating a sink with a suitable formatter. The process is described in the [Tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/formatters.html) (use [`add_console_log`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.setup.convenience) instead of `add_file_log` if you want to keep sending logs to the console). You may also need to add a few common attributes, such as timestamps, if you want them in your output. After setting up the sink all logs produced by `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` will be directed to that sink.